# Probability that every prefix of a toss sequence has more heads than tails

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

We toss a coin $n + m$ times. When we are done, there have been $n$ heads and $m$ tails, with $n > m$. All sequences of results are equally likely. For example, if $n = 2$ and $m = 1$, then $P(HHT) = P(HTH) = P(THH) = \frac{1}{3}$.

Now what is the probability that during the course of the experiment, the number of heads we've seen so far is always *strictly* larger than the number of tails we've seen so far?

My first thought was to define $A_i$ to be the event that we've always have more heads than tails up to the end of the $i$th toss, and calculate $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+m}A_i)$, but then I got stuck.

Comment: So this is all conditional on the end result having $m$ heads and $n$ tails? i.e you want the probability that the substring of tosses 1 : k has more heads than tails given that the total string has n heads and m tails?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, that's right.

Comment: (my only hang up is that this is not really an 'experiment' one could do since we must look into the future, so I wasn't sure )

Comment: This is known as the ballot theorem. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem or Feller's probability book.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!